# Siri Sounds Robotic in macOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, siri, voice

Since I upgraded my MacBook Pro(mid-2012) to macOS Sierra the voice which is being used by Siri is unnatural.It sounds like the old iOS 6 Siri.I downloaded all the dictation voices but the problem persists.Somwhere on the internet I found a solution saying that enabling checkboxes under App Store auto-update fixes the issue but Siri still sounds the same.Does anyone have a concrete solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Siri natural (enhanced) voice has to download. If you've got a slow connection it might be a few days before Siri has the voice that you have become accustomed to.

Comment: Is there any way to see the progress of the voice being downloaded?